# How do I `connect` an UDP socket and let the OS choose the port and address

Tags: rust, udp, client

I want to send an UDP query to a server and receive it's response. In C it is: [call `socket` then `connect` then `write` then `read`](https://gist.github.com/kmkaplan/71cafa2f677cebb98e6ca2407cf20469). The operating system takes care of choosing a suitable local IP address and port to use.

I'm trying to do the same in Rust. But I can not find a way to get a [`UdpSocket`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html) without myself specifying the address and port. The closest I could do was:

```
fn main() {
    use std::net::{Ipv4Addr, UdpSocket};
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind((Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED, 12345)).unwrap();
    socket.connect("1.1.1.1:53").unwrap();
    socket.send(b"\x12\x34\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
                \x07example\x03com\x00\
                \x00\x01\x00\x01").unwrap();
    let mut buffer = [0; 512];
    let len = socket.recv(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    for b in &buffer[0..len] {
        print!("{:02x} ", b);
    }
    println!("");
}
```

This works but has two downsides compared to the C version.

1. it could fail if I specify a local port that is already in use,
2. the socket listens on *all* available addresses while the C version only listen on "suitable" address. This is important with UDP to avoid response spoofing.

   For example if I query 127.0.0.1, then the C version will automatically bind to the 127.0.0.1 address. The internet will not be able to spoof answers to my queries. Also, if I have two network interfaces, one connected to the internet, and one to my local network with IP 192.168.0.1, I can query a resolver on the local network, says 172.16.17.18. The C version will bind to the address 192.168.0.1 and I'll be sure that the answer is not comming from the internet.

How would I best do the same as the C version?

Edit: to explain the second point about finding a "suitable" address.

Comment: Can you clarify the second part of your question? The answer to the first is that you can bind port `0` to get a randomly-assigned one.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Binding port 0 solves the port part. Thank you. I have edited the question to explain the part about IP address.

Comment: the Rust API is the same then the C Posix API , what you describe here is the problem of UDP not Rust. I don't understand what you want, your point 2 is simply false.

Comment: @Stargateur no, the Rust API *requires* me to `bind`. I do not need to bind in C. See the link in my question.

Comment: guess Rust std choice this behavior, https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.5/tokio/net/struct.UdpSocket.html seem to follow the behavior you want or you could use crate libc to access to posix C api. Also bind to 1.1.1.1:0 should work the same

Comment: @Stargateur I just checked Tokio, and mio. They both have this same limitation. I guess I will have to go the libc route, which I was trying to avoid. Of course *if* I jnew the address to use I could bind it upfront. But it is quite difficult to find in a portable way.

Comment: Binding to `0.0.0.0` should act as a wildcard

Comment: @jmb This *is* what I am doing (`Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED`). But as explained in the description, this is *not* entirely satisfactory (point #2).

Comment: Are you sure that you're not getting a proper local address? I tested with `socket.local_addr()` after binding `(UNSPECIFIED, 0)`, and it is set correctly to the address of the interface.

Comment: @JPSugarbroad I had missed that. Thank you. If you'd make an answer with this, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not obvious, but if you bind the socket to `(UNSPECIFIED, 0)`, then when you connect to a remote address the local address is set to the appropriate interface address. (Port `0` means to auto-allocate a port, just like an unbound socket in C.) You can confirm this by calling `local_addr()` on the socket after a successful connection.

I apologize for the complexity of POSIX. :-)